# I have been asked to sketch the graph $y =\frac{x^3+1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus

I need to be able to show all point of interest, stationary point, asymptotes and where it meets the $x$ and $y$ axis. And be able to show the working.

Comment: Question edited to fit the appropriate LaTeX formatting. Besides on the question format, it's a signal of good question showing your effort done so far, or the point where there are issues.

Comment: i am struggling to get going on the question. Looking at it I can work out there is only one point where it crosses the axis (0,-1) on the x axis. But after that I am struggling.

Comment: @user104526: Hint: Start with a plot, see [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%5E3%2B1%29%2Fx%5E2)

Comment: Do this first $f(x)=\frac{x^3+1}{x^2}=x+x^{-2}$. $f'(x)=1-2x^{-3}$, $f''(x)= 6x^{-4}$. $2^{1/3}$is  C.P., the line $y=x$ is the asymptote, $(-1, 0)$ $x$-intercept The graph is always  concave up.

Comment: You hould start by the domain, examine the points where the function does not exist (its boundaries) with the help of limits (deducing asymptotes); after that you can examine the stationary points *candidates* (max/min) using the first derivative [(Fermat's Theorem)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_%28stationary_points%29).

Answer (score 2):

We give a partial answer that does not consider derivatives. Note that our function simplifies to $x+\frac{1}{x^2}$.

For $x$ close to $0$, our function is very large positive. Lightly draw $y$ very big positive on both sides of the line $x=0$ (the $y$-axis). The curve is asymptotic to the $y$-axis.

For $x$ large positive, $x+\frac{1}{x^2}$ is large, and very close to $x$. Draw the line $y=x$. For $x$ large, $y=x+\frac{1}{x^2}$ is a tiny bit *above* the line $y=x$. Draw it doing that.

Similarly, for $x$ large negative, $y=x+\frac{1}{x^2}$ is a tiny bit above the line $y=x$. That line is an (oblique) asymptote to the curve. Draw.

Once we have sketched in what happens near $0$ and when $|x|$ is large, we have a pretty good idea of the basic behaviour of the function. You can probably visually fill in what the curve should look like.

For finer detail, we can now turn to the derivative, and the second derivative. Little mechanical errors, and sign errors, are quite possible at this stage. The preliminary sketch we made before computing may serve to detect such errors.

Comment: That and the fact that the graph crosses the $x$-axis at $(-1,0)$ is plenty enough, I think.

Comment: The sketching, going through regions of increase/decrease, local max/min, concavity is one of the standard test/exam questions, and leaving out one of these loses marks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

first find domain ,assymptote ,roots(optional)
then calculate f'
then determine the sign of f'
and go on

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined everywhere except at $0$, where it has a vertical asymptote. It is continuous on its whole domain. It has an oblique asymptote (in both directions, being a rational function), because
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\dots,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-\dots x=\dots
$$
It can't intersect the $y$-axis and intersects the $x$-axis only at $\dots$.

The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\left(x+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)'=1-\frac{2}{x^3}=\frac{x^3-2}{x^3}
$$
that's quite easy to study.

The second derivative is $f''(x)=6/x^4$ that's everywhere positive.